# If a blue/green deployment fails on AWS, it leaves dangling instances. How do I ensure that old instances are terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-codepipeline, blue-green-deployment

We have Blue/green deployment configured on AWS so that when we release to production, we have the old instance running while a replacement instance is being set-up.

Each release creates a new autoscaling group and therefore new instances. If a release goes well, a replacement instances is created, code is deployed there and traffic is shifted over.

If a release fails, however, the instances created still remain, and so if we have multiple failures, we can have a very large number of heavy instances running without reason. Is there a way we can easily clean up these instances, or prevent it altogether perhaps? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on how you are doing your deployment, include code/script/templates.

Comment: @TimBasset So we're just uploading bash scripts (using s3) to the instances and executing them using user_data. For everything else, we're using AWS CodePipeline.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy leaves the green fleet there in case you need to trouble shoot why the deployment to green failed. CodeDeploy currently does not have an out-of-box solution to terminate green fleet automatically. However, you can listen to the failure of fleet-wide deployments via [CloudWatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudwatch-events.html) or [SNS event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/monitoring-sns-event-notifications.html), so you can take actions to terminate the green when you get notified. Make sure your event listener checks the deployment creator and the deployment status.